# Null reference exception on access HttpContext.Session value in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5, httpcontext

I got a `NullReferenceException` on access value of session from one controller which set on another controller though `HttpContext.Session`. This question might asked before and have an answer but non of answer is not fit with my problem. 
Here is my code for set session value:

```
public class OneController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string returnURL = "")
    {
         HttpContext.Session["Message"] = "Hello World!";
    }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnURL))
            {
                return Redirect(returnURL);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Another");
            }
}
```

And here how I tried to get its value from another controller:

```
public class AnotherController : Controller
{
    public AnotherController ()
    {

        var message = HttpContext.Session["Message"] != null ? HttpContext.Session["Message"].ToString() : "N/A"; //This line cause null reference exception
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid question: Do you have `<sessionState>` defined in the `<system.web>` section of your web.config file?

Comment: Why do you need to access the value in the constructor rather than say inside the action method?